# Proving Primes in an UFD

Tags: ring-theory

Here is my unique factorization domain: $\mathbb{R}[x_{1}, x_{2},...x_{n}]$. My goal is to show that for all $1 \le i < j \le n$ the polynomial $x_{j} - x_{i}$ is irreducible. Since the ring is a UFD, it is enough to show that $x_{j} - x_{i}$ is prime, since {irreducibles} = {primes} in an UFD. Here is my attempt at a proof, but I am not sure if it is 100% strong:

Suppose $x_{j} - x_{i}$ divides $f(x_{1},...,x_{n})*g(x_{1},...,x_{n})$. Suppose $x_{j} - x_{i}$ does not divide $f(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ Then by division algorithm (with respect to the variable $x_{j}$) I get: $f(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = (x_{j} - x_{i})Q + R(x_{1},...x_{j-1},x_{j+1},...,x_{n})$. Suppose further that $x_{j} - x_{i}$ does not divide $g(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ Then by division algorithm (with respect to the variable $x_{j}$) I get: $g(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = (x_{j} - x_{i})Q_{2} +  R_{2}(x_{1},...x_{j-1},x_{j+1},...,x_{n})$. Then $fg = R_{1}R_{2}+...other stuff$. Contradicts the fact that fg is divisible by $x_{j} - x_{i}$

Comment: Or you could use that the quotient by $x_i-x_j$ is $R[x_1,\ldots, \hat{x_j},\ldots, x_n]$, which is a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear (to me) how the expression
$$fg=R_1R_2+\ldots\text{"other stuff"},$$
contradicts the fact that $fg$ is divisible by $x_j-x_i$. How about this very direct approach instead:

If $x_j-x_i=fg$ for some $f,g\in\Bbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ then
$$1=\deg(x_j-x_i)=\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g),$$
so either $\deg(f)=0$ or $\deg(g)=0$, meaning that either $f$ or $g$ is a unit, so $x_j-x_i$ is prime.

Comment: I point was since $R_{1}R_{2}$ is not divisible by $x_{j} - x_{i}$ while the other terms are, we see that fg cannot be divisible by  $x_{j} - x_{i}$, a contradiction. But I like your answer better

Comment: @user758469 You might then want to make explicit that $x_j-x_i$ does not divide $R_1$ and $R_2$, and then *prove* that this implies that $x_j-x_i$ does not divide $R_1R_2$.